# Why is my numeric data being treated as an object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame in Pandas being treated as an object when the data is actually numeric. How do I fix this issue? I'm assuming this is happening because I have certain values within my columns that are not numeric - which I am trying to convert to `NaN`. When I try and run the `to_numeric`function, it returns everything as NaN, which is not what I am expecting.

Imagine my data looks something like

```
A B C D
X Y Z 53
X Y Z 65
X Y Z 22
X Y Z 6/5/96
X Y Z 45
X Y Z 97
```

I am trying to make everything in column D stay, while making the `6/5/96` change to `NaN`, but everything I have tried results in `NaN` for all the values in column D. When I look up the `dtypes` it lists column D as an object, but they are definitely numerical values.

How do I fix my DataFrame to look like this, without altering the actual numerical values?

```
A B C D
X Y Z 53
X Y Z 65
X Y Z 22
X Y Z NaN
X Y Z 45
X Y Z 97
```

---

I am using Tabula to convert a PDF to a CSV.

```
df = pd.read_csv('TEST.csv')
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'], errors='coerce')
```

Do you think during the Tabula PDF to CSV conversion, that my data is losing its data type?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: There really is not much for me to post. I'll add what I am working with.

Comment: I have no idea what that `csv` looks like and it's kinda the whole point.  Also include the top several lines of the `csv` and what the results look like after running your code on that portion of the csv.

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), but all `int` values are cast to `float`s:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'], errors='coerce')
```

But if mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
```

Or if trailing whitespaces:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'].astype(str).str.strip(), errors='coerce')
```

EDIT:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'].str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce')
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'].replace(',','', regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: When I do this, every numeric value in column D also becomes NaN. This is the issue.

Comment: This is still resulting in all NaN values... Edit: Just edited the question

Comment: Hmmm, what is `print (df['D'].apply(type))` ?

Comment: `Name: D, Length: 200, dtype: object` So clearly, it is reading this as objects rather than numerical values, but I have no idea why. I wonder if this is happening when I am converting my data from PDF to CSV.

Comment: Yes, it is `print (df['D']).dtypes`. But I need `print (df['D'].apply(type))` - it is obviolusly something else as `object`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I think it is difference between `type` and `dtypes`.

Comment: How would I fix something like this?

Comment: Ok, so problem is all my 3 solution return all `NaN`s values for column `D` ?

Comment: Yes - that is the problem.

Comment: OK. So main problem of `dtype` `object` is it is not clear what is `object` - `dict`, 'list', 'set', `string`? So need `print (df['D'].apply(type))` for return new Series with `class`es. Can you try it?

Comment: Class is returning as string.

Comment: All values? Or only some?

Comment: All the values.

Comment: Ok, if check `print (df['D'].tolist())` what it return for numeric?

Comment: Basically prints a list of all the numbers in Column D within quotes...`['6/12/2017  12', '274,965', '1,339,934', '3,621,761', '3,652,203', '48,343,951', '277,587,609', '334,820,423', '2,848,974', '2,940,543', '5,726,059', '7,053,523', '29,440,621', '31,364,350', '32,937,919', '48,327,535', '63,488,232', '86,896,934', '311,024,689', '26,019']`.....

Comment: Need replace `,` to empty string - check edited answer.

Comment: You are really the best. I can't thank you enough. This has been bothering me for quite some time today! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you import the dataframe, column `'D'` is object and the individual elements are `string`.

You can use `pd.Series.str.is_numeric` with `where`.

```
df.D.where(df.D.str.isnumeric())

0     53
1     65
2     22
3    NaN
4     45
5     97
Name: D, dtype: object
```

If you have mixed type, both strings and actual numeric types, you can use both `to_numeric` and `str.isnumeric`

```
df.D.where(df.D.str.isnumeric() | pd.to_numeric(df.D, 'coerce').notnull())

0     53
1     65
2     22
3    NaN
4     45
5     97
Name: D, dtype: object
```

In either case, use `assign` to create a copy with the new column

```
df.assign(
    D=df.D.where(df.D.str.isnumeric() | pd.to_numeric(df.D, 'coerce').notnull())
)

   A  B  C    D
0  X  Y  Z   53
1  X  Y  Z   65
2  X  Y  Z   22
3  X  Y  Z  NaN
4  X  Y  Z   45
5  X  Y  Z   97
```

---

This should also work:

```
df.assign(D=df.D.where(pd.to_numeric(df.D, 'coerce').notnull()))

   A  B  C    D
0  X  Y  Z   53
1  X  Y  Z   65
2  X  Y  Z   22
3  X  Y  Z  NaN
4  X  Y  Z   45
5  X  Y  Z   97
```

Comment: How would I implement that?

Comment: `TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @Mitchell woops... fixed.

Comment: I think you can point it is really not recomended solution - `int`s with `float`s :(

Comment: @jezrael Notice that I'm not altering the column at all except to place `np.NaN` where the element couldn't otherwise be interpreted as a number.  I'm of a mixed opinion on whether that is appropriate.

Comment: @piRSquared still treating all of them as Strings.

Comment: @Mitchell ok... unless you edit your post with a complete code sample that produces the problem... I'm out.  Good luck